# Find recursion level depth in while loop

Tags: php, sql, recursion

I have this function:

```
function showItems($parent = 0,$level=0) {
$q = 'SELECT id, bg_category, parent, url FROM products_categories WHERE parent = "'.$parent.'" ORDER BY bg_category';
$q = mysql_query($q);
if(mysql_num_rows($q)) {
    echo '<ul id="mmenu">';
    while($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
    $level++;
        echo '<li class="'.$level.'">';
        echo '<a href="../products/'.$r[3].'">',$r[1],'</a>';
        showItems($r[0],$level + 1);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

How I can get the level depth so each to be equal of the depth level?
As it works now it drows  to  which is the number of loops, but not the depth level.. How this function needs to be changed?
Help Please, Thank you !

Comment: Please rephrase, I don`t understand what you want

Comment: Ops, I found the problem ! I had to remove  $level++;
 to make it work !. Sorry guys for wasting your time, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I found the problem ! I had to remove $level++; to make it work !. Sorry guys for wasting your time, thanks !

Comment: you might make use of a static variable within your function so that you don't need to propagate it through a parameter:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php